# Bootstrap 4 carousel not working inside tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Im having a hard time figuring out whats going on here. I need to show a different carousel based on a selected tab, but something seems to be in conflict as it starts breaking when switching between tabs.
Is this a library issue?

```
<div class="bs-example">
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#TAB1" data-toggle="tab">TAB1</a></li>
<li><a href="#TAB2" data-toggle="tab">TAB2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="TAB1">
  <div id="myCarousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150?text=1" alt="First Slide"/></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150?text=2" alt="Second Slide"/></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150?text=3" alt="Third Slide"/></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="TAB2">
  <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150?text=4" alt="First Slide"/></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150?text=5" alt="Second Slide"/></div>
      <div class="carousel-item"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150?text=6" alt="Third Slide"/></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vscotLab/1/)

Comment: I too haven't been able to debug this but I noticed that when I switch from a tab that does not have carousel to a tab that has one, the `.active` is not getting removed from the current tab. Hence, in the tab with carousel, both the tabs are shown one below the other. And its not true vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is an issue with Bootstrap 4. It is caused by the carousel indicator active class interfering with the `tab-pane` and `carousel-item` active class

The documentation vaguely mentions nesting, but it's not clear if they are referring to other components, or just carousels in general (I would assume the latter)

> Please be aware that nested carousels are not supported, and carousels
>   are generally not compliant with accessibility standards.
>
> https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/

There doesn't seem to be any way around this as removing the active class breaks the carousel.

Answer (score 1):

My code manualy add and remove class `.active` to/from `.nav-link` and `.tab-pane` elements. And it's work.

HTML+Bootstrap-v4.0-beta

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6">
        <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column flex-sm-row" role="tablist" id="myTabs">
            <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link active" href="#overview" role="tab">Overview</a>
            <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link" href="#characteristic" role="tab">Characteristic</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="tab-content mt-2" id="tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="overview" role="tabpanel">
                <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://englishxp.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/some_any.jpg" alt="First slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://uacrisis.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Eurovision2017Ukraine-825x400.png" alt="Second slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://media.sweetwater.com/store/manufacturer/Gibson/about/sg_full.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <p>The <strong>Gibson Les Paul</strong> is a solid body electric guitar that was first sold by the Gibson Guitar Corporation in 1952.[1] The Les Paul was designed by Gibson president Ted McCarty, factory manager John Huis and their team, along with guitarist/inventor Les Paul.</p>
                <p>The Les Paul was originally offered with a gold finish and two P-90 pickups. In 1957, humbucking pickups were added, along with sunburst finishes in 1958. The sunburst 1958–1960 Les Paul – today one of the best-known electric guitar types in the world – was considered a failure, with low production and sales. For 1961, the Les Paul was redesigned into what is now known as the Gibson SG. This design continued as a separate guitar when the traditional single cutaway, carved top bodystyle was re-introduced in 1968. The Les Paul has been continually produced in countless versions and editions since. Along with Fender's Telecaster and Stratocaster, it was one of the first mass-produced electric solid-body guitars. Les Pauls have been used in many genres, including rock, country, pop, soul, rhythm and blues, blues, jazz, reggae, punk, and heavy metal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="characteristic" role="tabpanel">
                <table class="table table-sm">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" class="table-info text-center"><strong>Construction</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-4">Body type</td>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-8">Solid, Single cut</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-4">Neck joint</td>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-8">Sent-in</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-4">Scale</td>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-8">24.75"</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" class="table-info text-center"><strong>Woods</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-4">Body</td>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-8">Mahogany, Maple top</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-4">Neck</td>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-8">Mahogany</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-4">Fretboard</td>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-8">Ebony</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" class="table-info text-center"><strong>Hardware</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-4">Bridge</td>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-8">Tune-o-matic</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-4">Pickup(s)</td>
                            <td class="d-inline-block col-8">A Burstbucker 3 humbucker at the bridge, P-90H at the neck, and a piezoelectric built into the bridge.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  let activeTab = $('#myTabs a').filter('.active');

  $('#myTabs a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    activeTab.removeClass('active');
    $(activeTab.attr('href')).removeClass('active');

    activeTab = $(this);

    activeTab.addClass("active");
    $(activeTab.attr('href')).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/senenkovitaliy/pen/rGyLRB?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a workaround for my own project. I have 5 tabs, the first (home page) had a carousel in it, the other 4 were just standard pages. I don't have time to implement it for your example, but just briefly, this is how I fixed mine:

1.
Save the current page/tab id to a variable on load, by searching for the link with a class of active. Take off the hash so we can use it to target the newly clicked element.

```
var currentPage = $('.nav-item a').filter('.active');
var pId = $(currentPage).attr('href');
var currentPageId = pId.substring(1, pId.length);
var prevPageId;
var pageId;
```

2.
When a new tab is clicked, save the initial tab/page id as a variable (prevPageId), get the id of the current page, then manually reset and update the classes on the previous and current tabs. This is the part that Bootstrap is messing up. For me it was intermittently removing the 'fade' class, and sometimes having two tabs with 'active'. Also, when I clicked back to the carousel (tab 1), it was not adding a class of 'active' to the 1st carousel item, so I have to do this manually.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 $(".nav-item a").click(function(event) {

  prevPageId = currentPageId;
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  pageId = href.substring(1, href.length);
  currentPageId = pageId;
  event.preventDefault();

  $('#' + prevPageId).removeClass('tab-pane fade show active');
  $('#' + prevPageId).addClass('tab-pane fade');
  $('#' + prevPageId).attr("aria-expanded","false");

  $('#' + currentPageId).removeClass('tab-pane fade');
  $('#' + currentPageId).addClass('tab-pane fade show active');
  $('#' + currentPageId).attr("aria-expanded","true");

  if (currentPageId === 'home') {
     $('.carousel-item:first').addClass('active');
  }

 });


});
```

I'm new-ish to this so the above code could be better I'm sure but it works, that's the main thing!

Answer (score 0):

If you can compile the bootstrap from the source all you have to do is to exlude the `'.carousel-item'` selector. Edit `'\js\src\tab.js'` and just replace (line 151 at the time of writing):

```
const active = $(container).find(Selector.ACTIVE)[0]
```

with:

```
const active = $(container).find(Selector.ACTIVE).not('.carousel-item')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is due to interference `.active` class tab with carousel

```
 $( ".carousel-inner .carousel-item" ).first().addClass( "active" );
```